# how to triggerclick on key 13

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<input type="text" id="search" autocompleteoff>
```

which open an auto suggestions box with this code:

```
<div class="search-results">
<a class="qss" href="www.domain.com/page1">Lorem Lipsum Dolar</a>
<a class="qss" href="www.domain.com/page1">Lorem Lipsum Dolar</a>
<a class="qss" href="www.domain.com/page1">Lorem Lipsum Dolar</a>
<a class="qss" href="www.domain.com/page1">Lorem Lipsum Dolar</a>
<a class="qss" href="www.domain.com/page1">Lorem Lipsum Dolar</a>
<a class="qss" href="www.domain.com/page1">Lorem Lipsum Dolar</a>
<a class="qss" href="www.domain.com/page1">Lorem Lipsum Dolar</a>
<a class="qss" href="www.domain.com/page1">Lorem Lipsum Dolar</a>
</div>
```

and i am using this javascript to move within suggestions with keyboard arrow keys:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
window.displayBoxIndex = -1;

$("#search").keyup(function(e) 
{
        if (e.keyCode == 40) 
        {  
            Navigate(1);
        }
        if(e.keyCode==38)
        {
            Navigate(-1);
        }

});

var Navigate = function(diff) {
    displayBoxIndex += diff;
    var oBoxCollection = $(".qss");
    if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length)
         displayBoxIndex = 0;
    if (displayBoxIndex < 0)
         displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
    var cssClass = "selected";
    oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass).eq(displayBoxIndex).addClass(cssClass);
}   
});
```

how do i make this javascript to trigger the click on the selected item when i press enter (key 13)

**also please note that when the search input field is focused i have already attached a click trigger to that with 13 that takes me to the global search results page. which is**

```
$('#search').keypress(function(x){if(x.keyCode==13){q=$(this).val();if(q!=this.d‌​efaultValue){
$('#vrid').click();
}
```

**so i want something Conditional that if the focus is on input that it takes to search results page (on key 13) else if focus on the suggested item it takes to the href of that item (on key 13).**

Please help
thanks guys

Comment: can't understand the problem >?

Comment: i want to add a condition that on key 13 .click(); where the class selected is added

Comment: Can you include the code where you attached an event to #search keypress/keyup for key 13?

Comment: $('#search').keypress(function(x){if(x.keyCode==13){q=$(this).val();if(q!=this.defaultValue){
     $('#vrid').click();}

Comment: Thanks, though it would be better if you edit your question instead of posting it as a comment so that others will see it easily as well... also, where and what is the .qss element?

Comment: .qss element is the <a> tag inside the search-results div actually the selected item to be clicked on enter has the class qss all of the item has qss and the selected one is class="qss selected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment that the below code is how you attached the event for key 13 and on the assumption that the links have the `selected` class:

Please see if the below works for you. Please replace your current code for `#search` `keypress` with this.

```
$('#search').keypress(function(x){
  if(x.keyCode==13){
    if ($('.selected').length) {
      var loc = $(".selected")[0].href;
      window.location.href = loc;
    } else {
      q = $(this).val();
      if (q!=this.d‌​efaultValue) {
        $('#vrid').click();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

See this in action in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/yqxezatg/)

Comment: i used your code right after my code but unfortunately it has stopped the existing navigate function as well :(

Comment: do you mean to replace this code with my existing keycode that was for #search??

Comment: you have to replace your existing keypress event handler (the one you posted at the comments) with the code I provided, have you tried that?

Comment: yes i did, and it stops all thejavascript on the website :(

Comment: I added a fiddle to my answer, you may see my code in action. It works fine on my end, also, I changed the property of #search from 'autocompleteoff' to autocomplete="off"

Comment: Thank you so very much for kind help, i am still trying to figure out that why it stops my code when i add the above snippet but i am doing it currently as i get success ill mark the answer for other people also, again thank you so much for your assistance and help :)

Comment: No problem, I hope I could have helped you get it working on your implementation but I don't have access to the actual page. Crossing fingers for you to have it working soon.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `selected` class is being added to the links, once the enter key is pressed:

```
var location = $(".selected")[0].href;
window.location.href = location;
```

update code:

```
$("#search").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40)
        Navigate(1);
    if (e.keyCode == 38)
        Navigate(-1);
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // say goodbye to the page!
        var location = $(".selected")[0].href;
        window.location.href = location;
    }
});
```

Comment: can you put that piece into the javascript code please? i have low java knowledge and i am confuse on what line i have to add this

Comment: @HarrisJones I added the code above. Replace your current keyup callback with this.

Comment: Thanks alot @Keizom, my console log says
TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: @HarrisJones That's because I assumed the selected class was being added to the links, and it appears it is not. I don't see any correlation between your Navigate code and your `div.search-results` so I don't know what to change.

Comment: the selected class is added to the links and it change the color and also move up and down upon pressing arrow keys, but when i hit enter it takes the input field focused and takes me to search results page, because before this all theres a java for #search keypress 13

Comment: @HarrisJones I understand what you are trying to accomplish but I mean I think I am missing something in your code (i.e. literally code missing). That aside, perhaps `$(".qss")` needs to be changed to `$(".search-results a")`?

Comment: no actually there is a global <a> as well in the search-results so i just want it to be limited to .qcss, i have updated the question, i think you will get the point now , i have added what qcss is and the existing key 13 code as well

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if I understood by your description then I would have used following approach if I were your.

I would suggest to use dropdown instead of 'div' for search results.
When navigate to search results set focus on dropdown instead of search 'textbox'.
When a search result item is focused set text of link in search textbox.
When you hit enter key, handle it for both textbox and dropdown, if dropdown is focused navigate browser to selected items link and if textbox is focused display your search page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i got your pointbut i am using it on an ajax based website, i dont want to add the focused value into the search field as it suggest when writing on it, can you tell me how do i add a trigger click into this where it puts the class selected on key 13?

Answer (score 0):

hi what i understand by your saying here is my try...

```js
$( ".search-results" ).keypress(function( e ) {
  if ( e.which == 13 ) {
    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent the default behaviour.
     
    // write down your conditions you want to execute..
    
  }  
});
```

hi you can try like this may it work

```js
$("div a").on("keypress",function(e){ // here div will be the container of the all <a> tags on which you want to get your url work.
  if(e.which == 13){ 
    //then over ride your code here for key press 13 and change the url
  }
});
```

Comment: i tried to add this code below my javascript function and the result is the same, on pressing enter its taking me to the url+input.val

Comment: i want to overright the last key13 command set for #search input and do the new key 13 if links has selected class in them

Comment: @Harris Jones hi on which bases you are changing the url .? can you say .? by  element's focus..?? if yes the you can chek where the focus is

Comment: no basically what happens is, i have a search input field, and when someone start writing the keyword it loads where user stops and show some suggestions as an <a> links in a <div>

through the question java i am able to move up and down in suggested <a> with keyboard but when hit enter on any suggestion it actually triggers the enter on the input field which is focused all the time and opens the search page instead of a url from the list <a class="selected" href="URL">

Comment: you can try with the $("div a").on("keypress",function(e){ if(e.which == 13){ //then over ride your code here for key press 13 and change the url
}
});